# Drop down list value returns to ---select--- after page refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html.dropdownlistfor, html-select

So in my application the user will select a name from the drop down list, click 'view' and the corresponding values will display on page.

A hyperlink is then used to sort the list in ascending order.  For this to happen the page refreshes and displays the new order of the list.

The value of the drop down list returns back to its original value of 'select' instead of remaining the name of the person selected.

My Model:

```
public class HolidayList
    {
        public List<Holiday> HList4DD { get; set; }
        public List<Person> PList4DD { get; set; }

        public int currentPersonID { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }

        public HolidayList()
        {
            HList4DD = new List<Holiday>();
            PList4DD = new List<Person>();
            }
        }
    }
```

---

my controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ViewResult Index(int HolidayDate)
        {
            var holidays = db.Holidays.Include("Person");

            HolidayList model = new HolidayList();

            model.currentPersonID = HolidayDate;
            model.PList4DD = db.People.ToList();           
            model.Categories = holidays.Select(x => new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Value = x.Id.ToString(),
                                                Text = x.Person.Name
                                            }
                                          );


            int data = HolidayDate;

            model.HList4DD = db.Holidays.Where(h => h.PersonId == HolidayDate).ToList();      

            return View(model);

        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ViewResult Index(string sortOrder, int? currentPersonID)
        {
            var holidays = db.Holidays.Include("Person");

            HolidayList model = new HolidayList();

            //not null
            if (currentPersonID.HasValue)
            {
                model.currentPersonID = currentPersonID.Value;

            }
            else
            {
                model.currentPersonID = 0;
            }

            model.PList4DD = db.People.ToList();

            ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "date" : "";
            var dates = from d in db.Holidays
                        where d.PersonId == currentPersonID.Value
                        select d;

            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "date":
                    dates = dates.OrderBy(p => p.HolidayDate);
                    break;
            }

            model.HList4DD = dates.ToList();

            return View(model);
        }
```

---

my view

i've tried a number of different attempts here, the following code worked but has the drop list problem

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HList4DD.First().HolidayDate,
                                new SelectList(Model.PList4DD, "Id", "Name"),
                               // Model.currentPersonID
                                "---Select---"
                                )  *@
```

---

my attempts to resolve this are:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("HolidayDate", Model.Categories, "---Select---")

 @Html.DropDownListFor("HolidayDate", x => x.HolidayDate, Model.Categories)
```

---

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Quick question: are you wanting to set the DropDownList to the value of currentPersonID?

Answer (score 2):

You are binding the DropDownFor to a wrong property.
Basically what you want to do is in your Model, create a new Property to bind the value selected by the dropdown.

```
public int SelectedDate {get;set;}
```

Then in your code front you wanted to use dropdownFor to bind the property like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedDate ,
   new SelectList(Model.PList4DD, "Id", "Name"),
   // Model.currentPersonID
   "---Select---"
)
```

Not this.

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HList4DD.First().HolidayDate ,
   new SelectList(Model.PList4DD, "Id", "Name"),
   // Model.currentPersonID
   "---Select---"
)
```

Finnaly, in the action that you wanted to do the sorting, you will need to pass the SelectedDate into the action. Then before you returning it,  assign it to Model. And the whole thing will work like magic.